# Почему в массиве $_POST null при ajax-запрсе?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Имеется 2 поля и кнопка для отправки данных на сервер ajax-ом

Вот `JavaScript`:

```
$('#find-btn').click(function () {
    if($('#from').val() == 0 && $('#to').val() == 0)
    {
        alert("Вы не заполнили поля для поиска!");
        return;
    }
    else {
        var findFrom = $('#from').val();
        var findTo = $('#to').val();
        var data = 'from=' + findFrom + '&to=' + findTo;
        console.log(data); /*Данные записались*/
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: './php/search.php',
            data: data,
            error: function () {
                alert("error on ajax search");
                /*Ошибок нет*/
            }
        })
    }
    return false;
})
```

Вот `PHP`:

```
var_dump($_POST] //array(0) { }
if(isset($_POST['from']) and (isset($_POST['to'])))
{
    echo 'yes!';
    /*Тут по прежнему false*/
}
```

`var_dump($_POST)` так же показывает что в массиве ничего нет.

Comment: Неправильный формат переменной `data`, попробуй вот так `var data = { from: findFrom, to: findTo }`

Comment: вы пытаетесь передать данные как будто они `$_GET`, а принимаете как `$_POST`

Comment: @S.Pronin оба формата эквивалентны

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев не путайте человека. Правильно он передает. Ошибка точно не в этом.

Comment: забыл сказать что это все на сервере, а не на локалхосте. Может из-за этого проблема?

Comment: А скрипт где? Попробуйте сдампить все заголовки или вызвать phpinfo(). Интересует метод, с которым вызывается скрипт.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я скинул весь скрипт, может чего то не хватает? какой именно параметр в phpinfo смотреть?

Comment: *А клиентский скрипт где находится? Также интересует HTTP-метод, который приходит серверному скрипту.* Спорим, там не POST, а какой-нибудь HEAD или OPTIONS?

Comment: @PavelMayorov сам аякс отрабатывает, ошибок не возникает, данные отправляются. Проблема в том что на php я их найти не могу. Весь проект в разных папках (php, js). Я немного не понимаю как посмотреть этот HTTP-метод ?

Comment: *****! **Попробуйте сдампить все заголовки или вызвать phpinfo()**

Comment: Или попробуйте использовать инструменты разработчика в браузере.

Comment: Или воспользуйтесь fiddler.

Comment: Сделайте уже хоть что-то для диагностирования проблемы!

Comment: секунду. есть ошибка в логе
 [:error] [pid 22649] [client 127.0.0.1:39955] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: from in ....

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, тс вам ответил, что ajax отработал, не путайте его посторонними вопросами. Попробуйте понять, что происходит у тс. Не спамте в комментариях, пожалуйста.

Comment: @borodatych а как он понял, что его ajax отработал?..

Comment: Спасибо всем! Извините, все работает

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ваш случай:

**JavaScript**:

```
$('#find-btn').click(function () {
    if($('#from').val() == 0 && $('#to').val() == 0)
    {
        alert("Вы не заполнили поля для поиска!");
        return;
    }
    else {
        var findFrom = $('#from').val();
        var findTo = $('#to').val();
        var data = { from: findFrom, to: findTo };
        console.log(data); /*Данные записались*/
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: './php/search.php',
            data: data,
            success: function(response){
                alert("response from search");
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error on ajax search");
                /*Ошибок нет*/
            }
        })
    }
    return false;
})
```

**PHP**:

```
include('dbconnection.php');
if(isset($_POST['from']) and (isset($_POST['to'])))
{
    echo 'yes!';
    /*Тут false*/
}
```

Как ответил **Pavel Mayorov**, оба варианты идентичны:

```
var data = { from: findFrom, to: findTo };
var data = 'from=' + findFrom + '&to=' + findTo;
```

Сэмулировал ситуацию, отработало:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для ленивых, поиграться можно так:
**test.php**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button>ЖМАКНИ</button>
<script>
    $('button').click(function () {
        var findFrom = 'findFrom_value';
        var findTo = 'findTo_value';
        var data = 'from=' + findFrom + '&to=' + findTo;
        console.log(data); /*Данные записались*/
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/test2.php',
            data: data,
            success: function(response){
                alert("response from search");
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error on ajax search");
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php

if( isset($_POST['from']) and (isset($_POST['to'])) )
{
    echo 'yes!';
    /*Тут false*/
}
else echo 'no!';
```

> Вопрос, если что помечен как общий, не стесняемся, добавляем, редактируем.

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ!
все ровно на php файле var_dump($_POST) дает array(0) { }

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: Обновил ответ - добавьте секцию `success`. Скорее всего будет `response from search`, раз говорите, что ошибка не срабатывает. Загляните в лог, там должен быть ответ с сервера. Что вернуло?